# How to convert a pyspark dataframe's column value to comma separated string

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

i am a pyspark newbie
need a little help to resolve below syntax error

```
ids_2_update = df_to_update.select("id_pk")
# below is obviously giving me exception …can only concatenate str (not "list") to str' …
connection_options["preactions"] = "delete from my_schema.my_table where id_pk in("+ids_2_update.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()+");"
appended_dynamic_df = DynamicFrame.fromDF(appended_df, glueContext, "convert_ctx")
glueContext.write_from_options(frame_or_dfc=appended_dynamic_df, connection_type=redshift_connection_type,connection_options=connection_options)
```

any idea how i can do it ?

**disclaimer** i need to use pyspark APIs not pySpark sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that rdd.collect() returns a list of the elements and you cannot concatenate a string and a list, so you first need to convert the list to a comma separated string to put it in the in clause. You could try something like that:

```
connection_options["preactions"] = "delete from my_schema.my_table where id_pk in("+','.join(ids_2_update.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())+");"
```

This assumes that the elements in the column are strings, otherwise you should cast them to string first.

Comment: this worked fine in my local pyCharm ... but in my AWS AWS ETL ... i get error .... ((<class 'NameError'>, NameError("name 'join' is not defined"),.... but my understanding is this is from standard package ...  can you confirm what package i need to add in AWS Glue ETL ?

Comment: The join method on string objects is built-in, so there is no need to install any additional packages. You could take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). Are you sure that the code is exactly the same in your AWS Glue ETL? From the error, I understand that the interpreter identifies the join as a variable and not as a function on the comma string, so perhaps the "." is missing before join?